Is there a way to create a Pandas series via string iteration?
I want to create a Pandas series that has a string and add a number/counter that iterates up to a certain number.
For example
Students = pd.Series(f"Student_{i}" for i in i < len(5))

and the output would be a pandas series that contains the following values:
['Student_1', 'Student_2', 'Student_3', 'Student_4', 'Student_5']


Did you try this?  Did it work?  What happened?

fancy python: pd.Series(map('Series {}'.format, range(1,6)))

Show a test script plus error message.

Have you done a Python tutorial? I'd recommend doing that first cause SO isn't really built to teach the basics. Any good tutorial should cover the use of range and for-loops.

You were on the right track but your syntax is wrong. for i in i < len(5) does nothing because you are never defining i.
Instead, you need to use a loop like this:
Students = pd.Series(f"Student_{i}" for i in range(1,6))

Output:
0    Student_1
1    Student_2
2    Student_3
3    Student_4
4    Student_5
dtype: object


It would help to mention how this fixes the problem.

use a list comprehension within the pandas series constructor, see my code below;
import pandas as pd

#create pandas series with a string and counter
students = pd.Series([f"Student_{i}" for i in range(1, 6)])

print(students)


You might do it following way
import pandas as pd
s = "Student_" + pd.Series(range(1,6)).astype(str)
print(s)

output
0    Student_1
1    Student_2
2    Student_3
3    Student_4
4    Student_5
dtype: object

Explanation: I created series from range(1,6) (observe that range is inclusice-exclusive) convert it to strs and prefix with Student_

Another option is to use range(5) and add 1: s = "Student_" + pd.Series(range(6)).add(1).astype(str)

The problem is that f"Student_{i}" for i in i < len(5) isn't valid. i < len(5) doesn't iterate anything so it can't be used as the value generator in a for loop. Use range(5) instead. range generates the numbers for your generator.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> Students = pd.Series(f"Student_{i}" for i in range(1,6))
>>> Students
0    Student_1
1    Student_2
2    Student_3
3    Student_4
4    Student_5
dtype: object

